# How to disable vim source .cshrc when running external command?

Tags: external-command

I'm running external command inside vim by `:!command`.
Noticed vim will source .cshrc before run the command, because I've added some echo in the .cshrc.
Is there a way to force vim don't source the .cshrc?

Answer (score 1):

`-f` tells `csh` not to source its startup scripts, so you need to tell Vim to give that flag to the shell.

`:!` and `!` use the shell specified in the `shell` option, with flag(s) from the `shellcmdflag` option.  By default, that is `-c`, which has to come immediately before the command to run.  If you want additional options, you'll need to insert them before that:

```
set shellcmdflag=-f\ -c
```